# How to create dummy rows in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have the following table:

| loan_id | first_term | term | month_due_time | MOB | dpd | loan_principal | dpd30p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202006 | 202006 | 5/7/2020 | 3 | 99 | 600000 | 600000 |
| 1 | 202006 | 202007 | 5/8/2020 | 4 | 95 | 600000 | 600000 |

If I want to create some dummy rows with MOB spans from 1 to 6, what can I do? The desired output is:

| loan_id | first_term | term | month_due_time | MOB | dpd | loan_principal | dpd30p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202006 | 202006 | 5/7/2020 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 202006 | 202006 | 5/7/2020 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 202006 | 202006 | 5/7/2020 | 3 | 99 | 600000 | 600000 |
| 1 | 202006 | 202007 | 5/8/2020 | 4 | 95 | 600000 | 600000 |
| 1 | 202006 | 202006 | 5/7/2020 | 5 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 202006 | 202006 | 5/7/2020 | 6 |  |  |  |

Comment: What's the RDBMS you're using?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Presto

Comment: try COALESCE. Please see https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `values()` and `cross join` to generate the rows, `left join` to bring in existing values, and `coalesce()` to replace values with defaults:

```
select lf.loan_id, lf.first_term,
       coalesce(t.term, 200006),
       coalesce(t.month_due_time, '2020-05-07'),
       v.mob,
       t.dpd, t.loan_principal, tdpd30p
from (select distinct loan_id, first_term
      from t
     ) lf cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) v(mob) left join
     t
     on t.loan_id = lf.loan_id and t.first_term = lf.first_term and
        t.mob = v.mob
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very similar to the one offered by @Gordon Linoff but uses the sequence functions offered by Trino.

We use `sequence(start, stop)` to generate the range and then convert into a column and perform a `RIGHT JOIN` followed by filling in the default values using `coalesce`

```
WITH rev_table(loan_id, first_term, term, month_due_time, MOB, dpd, loan_principal, dpd30p)
         AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES (1, 202006, 202006, date ('2020-07-05'), 3, 99, 600000, 600000),
                     (1, 202006, 202007, date ('2020-08-05'), 4, 95, 600000, 600000))),
     mob_table(MOB) AS (
         SELECT *
         from UNNEST(SEQUENCE(1, 6))
     )

SELECT coalesce(loan_id, 1) as loan_id,
       coalesce(first_term, 202006) as first_term,
       coalesce (term, 202006) as term,
       coalesce (month_due_time, date('2020-07-05')) as month_due_time,
       mt.MOB as MOB,
       dpd, loan_principal, dpd30p
FROM rev_table rt RIGHT JOIN mob_table mt on mt.MOB = rt.MOB;
```